# Ajax calling situation on asynchorous call

Tags: ajax, return

I am stuck with my specific problem.
I want to return false if the data comes using ajax.
Here is my code:

```
  <script>
    function verifydom(form)
        {
            var domnam = form.domname.value;            
            if (domnam == "")
            {
                alert("Please enter the Domain Name");
                    form.domname.focus();
                    return false;  
            }            
            else if(domnam.indexOf('.gov.in') <= 0){
                alert("Please enter valid domain name");
                    form.domname.focus();
                    return false;
            }
            else{                
                $.ajax({
                   type: "get",
                    url: "calling.php",
                    data: "domnam="+domnam,
                    success: function(msg){
                        if(msg!== ""){
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
     </script>
    <form name="frmDelegate" action="dlgdetail.php" method="POST" 
    onsubmit="return verifydom(document.frmDelegate);" autocomplete="off">
    input type="text" name="domname" id= "domname" 
    onkeyup="showResult(this.value);"/>            <input type="hidden" 
    id="chkmsg" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

The ajax call under 'else condition' would return some error message, So if an error comes, I want the form not to be submitted.
Okay, the problem is 'Else will work every time whether Ajax gives a message or not.
How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than blank message I would prefer to return a `JSON` message from the `calling.php` file.

```
$arr = array( "status" => "error", "message" => "error found");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

By doing this you are easily allowed to check whether the error is there or not. If `JSON` have any message then you should check by below code.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   url: "calling.php",
   data: "domnam="+domnam,
   success: function(msg){
   var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
       if(data.status == "error"){ // no need to check strictly
          return false;
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: same problem, return wouldn't work inside ajax call. :(

Comment: add `async: false` in request and try again